# Is it possible to have an enum that contains constructors for objects?

Tags: java, enums, constructor

I'm testing out a different sort of pattern.  I've already got the code working in a `switch` statement, but I'd like to try something a little more ecclectic... for research purposes.

Say I have 4 classes, `Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3`, and `Class4` that all extend `BaseClass`.  I want to put them into an `enum`, like so:

```
enum ClassFactories { 
  Class1(Class1.class), 
  Class2(Class2.class), 
  Class3(Class3.class), 
  Class4(Class4.class);

  private final Class factory;
  ClassFactories(Class factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  public BaseClass generate() {
    BaseClass b = null;
    try {
      b = (BaseClass)this.factory.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle any exceptions
    }
    return f;
  }
}
```

In a factory method that is passed an `int`, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
public void fakeMethod(int type) {
  BaseClass someClass = ClassFactories.values()[type].generate();
  someClass.doStuff();
}
```

Is there a cleaner/easier way of doing this?  I'm not so much concerned with readability (right now), I'm just curious if this is possible.

Comment: Why would you add enums and yet still pass an int?  Why not `fakeMethod(ClassFactories cf)`?

Comment: That's a good question.  Seems to make more sense to pass it as an enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Something like a 'Template Method' approach. So for example

```
public enum ClassFactory {
     Class1() {
          @Override public void generate() { 
               System.out.println("I'm in Class 1."); 
          }
     },
     Class2() {
          @Override public void generate() { 
               System.out.println("I'm in Class 2."); 
          }
     };
     //template method
     public abstract void generate();

   private static final Map<Integer, ClassFactory > lookup
   = new HashMap<Integer, ClassFactory >();

   static {
   for (ClassFactory s : EnumSet.allOf(ClassFactory.class))
         lookup.put(s.getIntValue(), s);
   }

   public static ClassFactory getValue(int intValue) {
      return lookup.get(intValue);
   }

}
```

### INVOCATION CODE

With the use of static imports, the client code calling this enumeration would look like:

```
Class1.generate();
Class2.generate();
//or better...
getClass().generate();
```

Or

```
public void fakeMethod(int type) {
  ClassFactory.getValue(type).generate();
}
```

Comment: In this case, it looks like the classes are declared inside of the enum.  Am I reading that right?

Comment: Yes, this code is not an exact answer to your question; but just to give an idea as to what is possible. So for an exact answer, you would need to change the implementation of the generate method and make it return a class instance instead of void. In the imeplementation, instead of "System.out.println("I'm in Class 1.");", you will instantiate a class and return it.